# converting typescript async/await generates a lot of javascript code

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, tsconfig, tsc

when I try to compile Typescript `async` function, it generates a lot of JavaScript code. I tried changing the `target` flag, the `noEmitHelpers` in the TSConfig file but gives me always the same thing. is this normal or am I missing something ?

**code in Typescript**

```
export async function f(msg: string) {
    
}
```

**generates :**

```
"use strict";
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __generator = (this && this.__generator) || function (thisArg, body) {
    var _ = { label: 0, sent: function() { if (t[0] & 1) throw t[1]; return t[1]; }, trys: [], ops: [] }, f, y, t, g;
    return g = { next: verb(0), "throw": verb(1), "return": verb(2) }, typeof Symbol === "function" && (g[Symbol.iterator] = function() { return this; }), g;
    function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step([n, v]); }; }
    function step(op) {
        if (f) throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");
        while (_) try {
            if (f = 1, y && (t = op[0] & 2 ? y["return"] : op[0] ? y["throw"] || ((t = y["return"]) && t.call(y), 0) : y.next) && !(t = t.call(y, op[1])).done) return t;
            if (y = 0, t) op = [op[0] & 2, t.value];
            switch (op[0]) {
                case 0: case 1: t = op; break;
                case 4: _.label++; return { value: op[1], done: false };
                case 5: _.label++; y = op[1]; op = [0]; continue;
                case 7: op = _.ops.pop(); _.trys.pop(); continue;
                default:
                    if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }
                    if (op[0] === 3 && (!t || (op[1] > t[0] && op[1] < t[3]))) { _.label = op[1]; break; }
                    if (op[0] === 6 && _.label < t[1]) { _.label = t[1]; t = op; break; }
                    if (t && _.label < t[2]) { _.label = t[2]; _.ops.push(op); break; }
                    if (t[2]) _.ops.pop();
                    _.trys.pop(); continue;
            }
            op = body.call(thisArg, _);
        } catch (e) { op = [6, e]; y = 0; } finally { f = t = 0; }
        if (op[0] & 5) throw op[1]; return { value: op[0] ? op[1] : void 0, done: true };
    }
};
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.f = void 0;
function f(params) {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
        return __generator(this, function (_a) {
            return [2 /*return*/];
        });
    });
}
exports.f = f;
```

Comment: Can you share your typescript/babel config? Try to reproduce it in https://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: On Codepen, when I paste your Typescript line, the compiled Javascript is `export async function f(msg) { }` and that's it. Is this file part of a module? Are there other files around or something? It's not alone, is it?

Comment: it is alone in a folder with tsconfig file

Comment: I have a folder witch contain t.ts file, typescript is installed globally, when I run the command ` tsc t.ts` it generates a file `t.js` with a lot of code, but when I run only `tsc` it generates JavaScript normally

Answer (score 4):

This is governed by the `target` property is `tsconfig.json`. And yes it's normal.

In order to emit async/await without transpilation, you need to set the target to `ES2017` or later. `ES3`, `ES5`, `ES2015` and `ES2016` all lack native support for async/await, so typescript adds polyfill functions to emulate them.

You can see this on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=0&jsx=4&ts=4.4.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwM4E8B2BjOAzArpmASwjRwAoBbJAcwC44kYpC1qBKOAbwCg4+5uAXyA). Click ".js" on the right hand side to see the compiled output. Then click "TS Config" at the top and try different "target" values. See how the compiled JS changes on the right.

[image: TSConfig target on typescript playground]

So you can set you project to `ES2017` or later, however if your code runs on an older javascript engine without native support for these features, then you code will not work. That's the tradeoff.

---

Somewhat interestingly, you'll note that if you have a `ES2015` or `ES2016` target, then it generates *less* extra code. This is because those versions support [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator), but still lack async/await support. And generators are used to polyfill async/await support. So because it doesn't need to also polyfill generators, you get less generated code.

Comment: I have a folder witch contain t.ts file, typescript is installed globally, when I run the command ` tsc t.ts` it generates a file `t.js` with a lot of code, but when I run only `tsc` it generates JavaScript normally

Comment: You probably need to provide a `--project` option that is a path your tsconfig. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR: Forgetting to use either of the following will cause error output in the terminal and unexpected output to your `index.js` file from your `index.ts` file

`"target": "esnext"` in your `tsconfig.json`

`tsc -p .`

For instance, if you targeted a single file like `index.js` instead of a project directory, you will get error output and unintended `index.js` output too

`tsc -p index.js`

Then your project will target the current directory.

#### If you would like to see a workflow starting with an empty directory

Create a new typescript file

`touch index.ts`

Put some `async` typescript code in it to prove the point later

```js
async function hello() {
  return "hi";
}
```

Install typescript globally (typically avoid global installs but do this here)

`npm i -g typescript`

Create a new `package.json`

`npm init -y`

Create a new `tsconfig.json`

`tsc --init`

Edit that file to be able to compile to human readable javascript

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext" /** latest js/es6, required for human readable js */,
   }
}
```

That is the only config you require for human readable js

Run tsc compile command on all your files that are in your current directory

`tsc -p .`

View your recently created `index.js` file

`cat index.js`

It will be human readable now.

Then feel free to create a `package.json` file

`npm init -y`

And store what you want in the scripts section to make it automated easily

```js
"scripts": {
    "dev": "yarn compile; yarn show; yarn start;",
    "compile": "tsc -p .",
    "show": "bat index.js",
    "start": "node index.js",
}
```

Then run any of the following

`yarn dev` # will run compile, show then start

`yarn compile` #
`yarn show` # similar to cat, bat just shows a file
`yarn start` # run your newly created `index.js` file with node to verify it works without errors